# Query only some attributes of Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

i've build Hyperledger Fabric channel and it was running well. But, i wanna get just some attributes only from that Hyperledger that have data structure like this

```
[
  {
     "name": "name-1",
     "class": "IV-A",
     "address": "dummy st.",
     "handphone": "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx",
     "status": "inactive"
  },
  {
     "name": "name-2",
     "class": "IV-A",
     "address": "dummy st. 7th",
     "handphone": "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx",
     "status": "active"
  },...
]
```

i wanna get just some attributes (name, address, and status), so we can get the return like this

```
[
  {
     "name": "name-1",
     "address": "dummy st.",
     "status": "inactive"
  },
  {
     "name": "name-2",
     "address": "dummy st. 7th",
     "status": "active"
  },...
]
```

is it possible to get those attributes via hyperledger directly without using couchdb? i know if we use couchdb we just need to create the view with some query in the "emit()", but is there any way to get that in hyperledger using chaincode or selector?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, it is done in the chaincode. The function in the chaincode decide what fields are returned.

Comment: is it safe if i just use "fields" argument in "GetQueryResultForQueryString" function? i've create this function in chaincode for the selector query, or is there another way to get it?

Comment: i tried like this 
```peer chaincode query -C mychannel -n school -c '{"Args":["QueryAssets","{\"fields\":[\"name\",\"address\",\"status\"],\"use_index\":\"_design/test\"}"]}' ``` and i get the result that i want

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your Hyperledger Fabric environment and data.

But you can check out this [chaincode](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/main/chaincode/marbles02/go/marbles_chaincode.go).

OR if you are OK to use 'invoke function', you can return value what you want.

```
return shim.Success([]byte($value))
```